# Regarding click on hyperlink and button using HtmlUnit Driver in java application

Tags: java, exception

i am trying to click on hyperlinks and buttons of webpage using HtmlUnit Driver in Java but i am failed in doing it. 
What code i have to write in java for performing such operation

Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you could post your source-code and eventual error-messages.

Getting-started and more is here:

> http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html

Do you have something similar like this?:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
page.getLinkWith("LinkName"), click()
```